# Getting Error 000151 from ArcGIS Projection?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arctoolbox, error-000151

I'm having big problems with arctoolbox  of ArcMap 10.3.1 to project almost all my layers from TM65 - Irish Grid to IRENET95 - Irish Tranverse Mercator.I always get the **error 000151** and the Help is not very helpful.
It looks like I can't choose the Geographic Transformation so "New Geographic Transformation" is the selected one.

Any idea??

You can try with "All Ireland" dataset here http://gis.teagasc.ie/soils/downloads.php.

Comment: I tried replicating this and could not using 10.3.1.  I projected it fine.
Are you using Project (Data Management) ?

Comment: Yes ArcToolbox-->Data Management Tools-->Projections and transformations-->Project. 
Then I choose that shp file as Input, IRENET95_Irish_Transverse_Mercator as Output Coordinate.
I couldn't choose between GeographicTransformations (optional).
And I got that error.
Did you fail to project it with ArcMap10.3.1 but you succeded with another version?

Comment: No, I projected it fine in 10.3.1. I didn't choose a geographic transformation though but I did have the option to. My next step for you would be to try a clean install or try a different program to project like QGIS or R.

Comment: If this appears to work for @GISKid and not for you using ostensibly the same steps and version then I would recommend listing exactly your detailed steps so that they can followed closely.  I'm not saying that GISKid is not already doing exactly the same as you but I suspect that there may be room for minor differences in your procedures/data that could have been overlooked.

Comment: It seems that you have an issue with a custom transformation you set up. I am not sure what you mean by "I can't choose the Geographic Transformation so "New Geographic Transformation" is the selected one". If you could provide a screenshot, that would be helpful to us I think.But it projected fine for me, it selects a combination of two transformations automatically (TM65_To+ETRS_1989_1 + IRENET95_To_ETRS_1989)

Comment: I sorted it out. As I said I couldn't choose between  the automatically transformations @PhilippNagel mentioned, so I created a new dummy transformation, I didn't have the the parameters to set the geographic transformation so I left all the requested parameters to 0 and created this dummy transformation. Creating this new dummy transformation I had back the ability to choose also between the default Geographic Transformations. Maybe a bug or something in my settings?